# Pasting a range from one workbook to another as an offset

Tags: excel, vba

The problem I'm having is that I am drawing a blank on copying a known range from one workbook to another, but after the last row ---but as an offset(3,0).  This is the entire code and really you can ignore the first 3/4 of it.... and start by where I'm setting ranges.  I would think that setting the range and doing a row offset from there, but clearly I'm not doing it correctly.

This is the line giving me an error: **Set rngFinalRange**... I know it's wrong, but I'm stuck. Thoughts?  Thank you!

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub TEST()


        Dim auditfolder As String
        Dim dumpfile As String
        Dim FSO As Object
        Dim fldstart As Object
        Dim wbkAudit As Workbook
        Dim wbkdump As Workbook
        Dim rngDumpCols As Range
        Dim rngDumpFullRange As Range
        Dim strAuditName As String
        Dim strDumpName As String
        Dim fl As Object
        Dim rngAuditFileRows As Range
        Dim rngAuditCols As Range
        Dim rngFinalRange As Range
        Dim rngauditrows As Range
        Dim lastrow as range


        Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")

        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
                .InitialFileName = "\\networkpath"
                .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then
                MsgBox "No file selected. Exiting."
        Exit Sub
        Else
                auditfolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        Set fldstart = FSO.getfolder(auditfolder)
        End If
        End With

        For Each fl In fldstart.Files
                If Right(fl.name, 3) = "xls" Then
                    If InStr(fl.name, "5ESS") Then
                         strAuditName = fl.name
                    ElseIf InStr(fl.name, "SelectDataDump") Then
                         strDumpName = fl.name
                    Else
                      MsgBox "Missing either the audit or selectdatadump file"
                    End If
                ElseIf Right(fl.name, 4) = "xlsx" Then
                    If InStr(fl.name, "5ESS") Then
                         strAuditName = fl.name
                    ElseIf InStr(fl.name, "SelectDataDump") Then
                        strDumpName = fl.name
                    Else
                      MsgBox "Missing either the audit or selectdatadump file"
                    End If
                End If
        Next fl

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Set wbkdump = Workbooks.Open(strDumpName)
        Set rngDumpCols = wbkdump.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(what:="*", After:=wbkdump.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
                          xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
        Set rngDumpFullRange = wbkdump.Sheets(1).Range("A1", rngDumpCols.Address)

        Set wbkAudit = Workbooks.Open(strAuditName)
        Set rngAuditCols = wbkAudit.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(what:="*", After:=wbkAudit.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
                           xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
        Set rngauditrows = wbkAudit.Sheets(1).Range("A1", rngAuditCols.Offset(0, -4).Address)
lastrow = wbkAudit.Sheets(1).Cells(65536, rngAuditCols.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngFinalRange = wbkAudit.Sheets(1).Range(lastrow.Offset(3, 0).Row)
                    rngFinalRange.Value = rngDumpFullRange.Value

        wbkAudit.Sheets(1).Columns.AutoFit
        wbkAudit.save

        MsgBox "Processing Complete!"


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lastrow` is declared in your code as a `Range` object but you are attempting to set it to a `Long` value:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196952.aspx

Try changing this...

```
lastrow = wbkAudit.Sheets(1).Cells(65536, rngAuditCols.Column).End(xlUp).Row
Set rngFinalRange = wbkAudit.Sheets(1).Range(lastrow.Offset(3, 0).Row)
```

...to this...

```
Set lastrow = wbkAudit.Sheets(1).Cells(65536, rngAuditCols.Column).End(xlUp)
Set rngFinalRange = wbkAudit.Sheets(1).Range(lastrow.Offset(3, 0).Address)
```

Comment: I tried this, but ended up with crazy results. I did, however make some progress.  this piece of code gives me only one cell value, but it's starting in the right spot:   Range("A" & lastrow).Offset(3, 0).Value = rngDumpFullRange.Value   The problem is that it's not pasting the whole rngDumpFullRange, which is A1:O204.  Thoughts?

Comment: lastrow = 125, so it's giving me the right value in A125, but that's it.

Comment: Ok, so you have `Range(lastrow.Offset(3, 0).Address)` but really you need something like `Range(lastrow.Offset(3, 0).Address, lastRow.offset(rngDumpFullRange.Rows.Count + 3, rngDumpFullRange.Columns.Count))`.  Make sense?  I don't have a worksheet like yours so I cannot test.